# discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code occasionally get a 400 bad request error with this command:

```
@owner_only
async def cmd_bootybomb(self, user_mentions, channel):
    userid = (str(user_mentions))
    await self.send_message(discord.Object(id = userid), bootybomb)
```

the variable `bootybomb` has been imported from another file which is just a bunch of links set as one variable.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Gamefolders\BootyBot\BootyBot\musicbot\bot.py", line 1289, in on_message
    response = await handler(**handler_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Gamefolders\BootyBot\BootyBot\musicbot\bot.py", line 115, in wrapper
    return await func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Gamefolders\BootyBot\BootyBot\musicbot\bot.py", line 877, in cmd_bootybomb
    await self.send_message(discord.Object(id = userid), bootybomb)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 831, in send_message
    data = yield from self.http.send_message(channel_id, content, guild_id=guild_id, tts=tts)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 137, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using discord api, if you read the description of send_message, if you send a message longer than 2000 chrs, discord raises a 400 request error.  For that Discord's character limit is 2000. As you can see, it's not actually a real error, discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400). It's a custom error made by discord API.

> client.send_message:
>   Raises:    HTTPException – Sending the message failed.

And I also asked the support a while ago regarding this question, and that was their explanation that they gave me. Basically, you got to keep the characters of your message under 2000.

This was the most common reason for this problem. But if your problem continues, your best bet of solving this problem is joining the support server for discord.py API in discord, and tell them your problem. Since it's mainly a API problem, not a python problem.